# Issues with @solana/spl-tokens pnpm is not saving this package to where I can't connect to the blockchain with the following .js file:

Tags: spl-token

```
const { Token, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } = require("@solana/spl-token");
const { Connection, PublicKey, Keypair } = require("@solana/web3.js");

async function main() {
// Your existing mint, payer, and recipient details
const mintPublicKey = new PublicKey("");
const recipientTokenAccount = new PublicKey("");
const payerKeypair = Keypair.generate(); // Your account that will pay for the transaction

// Establish a connection to the cluster
const connection = new Connection([link](https://rpc.ankr.com/solana_devnet/a62e9ca39b1ccedf47c1bd02af472a2438212b774438f46c4b8b10b3cb681d36), "confirmed");

// Create a new token instance
const token = new Token(
    connection,
    mintPublicKey,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    payerKeypair // Use the payer's keypair for signing transactions
);

// Amount to mint (consider decimals)
const amountToMint = 150000000; // Adjust based on your token's decimals

// Minting new tokens to the recipient's token account
await token.mintTo(
    recipientTokenAccount, // Token account of the recipient
    payerKeypair.publicKey, // Payer of the transaction
    [], // Multisig owners (if applicable)
    amountToMint // Amount to mint
);

console.log(`Minted ${amountToMint} tokens to ${recipientTokenAccount.toString()}`);
}

main().catch(err => {
console.error("Error executing the script:", err);
});
```

After running `pnpm install @solana/spl-tokens`, I get still:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@solana/spl-token'
Require stack:

/mnt/c/Users/segura23/SeguraSafeSwap_Token/SeguraSafeSwap_Solana3/solana-program-library/services/js/blockchainConnection.js
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
at Object. (/mnt/c/Users/segura23/SeguraSafeSwap_Token/SeguraSafeSwap_Solana3/solana-program-library/services/js/blockchainConnection.js:1:37)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'/mnt/c/Users/segura23/SeguraSafeSwap_Token/SeguraSafeSwap_Solana3/solana-program-library/services/js/blockchainConnection.js'
]
```

Comment: Could you share your `package.json` file. And check you installed `@solana/spl-token` not `@solana/spl-tokens` (extra s) as per your question

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the `spl-token` package with `pnpm install @solana/spl-token`